# How to add new permissions to admin when they have existing rights, Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a case where the admin has existing rights, and I need to update the admin to add new ones without updating or deleting the existing ones, but I have a code that works and a code that doesn't work because the first one is not accepted as a solution.

This is the code I have made that works as it should but is not accepted:

```
 public function run()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $permissions = [
            ['name' => 'show_email_to_providers_settings', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'add_email_to_providers_settings', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'modify_email_to_providers_settings', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'delete_email_to_providers_settings', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'show_email_to_providers_template', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'add_email_to_providers_template', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'modify_email_to_providers_template', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'delete_email_to_providers_template', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
        ];

        $role = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();

        Permission::query()->insert($permissions);

        $role->givePermissionTo(Permission::whereIn('name', array_column($permissions, 'name'))->get());
    }
```

For this code, I was told **you can give permissions directly**

So I made this other code seeing other examples:

```
public function run()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $formPermissions = [
            ['name' => 'show_email_to_providers_settings', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'add_email_to_providers_settings', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'modify_email_to_providers_settings', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'delete_email_to_providers_settings', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'show_email_to_providers_template', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'add_email_to_providers_template', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'modify_email_to_providers_template', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
            ['name' => 'delete_email_to_providers_template', 'guard_name' => 'api', 'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now],
        ];

        Permission::query()->insert($formPermissions);

        foreach ($formPermissions as $permission) {
            $permissionNames[] = $permission['name'];
        }

        $adminRole = Role::findByName('admin');

        $adminRole->givePermissionTo($permissionNames);
    }
```

This code gives me this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
> key constraint fails (`gps`.`role_has_permissions`, CONSTRAINT
> `role_has_permissions_permission_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
> (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `permissions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
> (SQL: insert into `role_has_permissions` (`permission_id`, `role_id`)
> values (134, 1))

Comment: Is this using the `spatie/laravel-permission` library? Knowing that is a key piece of addressing this. If so, you should be using the approaches listed on https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/basic-usage rather than directly manipulating the database.